# postgresql average of numrange

Tags: postgresql, range, average

I have a Postgresql table with following data

```
Power_range;unit; Date
[0.055,0.065];un_MW_el;14.01.1985
[0.02,0.02];un_MW_el;22.08.1985
[0.075,0.085];un_MW_el;09.04.1986
[0.055,0.055];un_MW_el;01.08.1986
[0.065,0.065];un_MW_el;19.01.1987
[0.075,0.075];un_MW_el;16.04.1987
[0.055,0.055];un_MW_el;15.05.1987
```

How can we query to list the average of numrange for each year/row?

The end result should be something like

```
0.060;1985
0.2;1985
0.80;1986 
0.055;1986
0.065;1987
0.075;1987
0.055;1987
```

Comment: `(upper(power_range)  + lower(power_range)) / 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if thereis inline avg math func, but you can easily mock it up with arythmetics:

```
t=# select ((lower(power_range) + upper(power_range))/2)::float(2),extract(year from d) avg From rt;
 float4 | avg
--------+------
   0.06 | 1985
   0.02 | 1985
   0.08 | 1986
  0.055 | 1986
  0.065 | 1987
  0.075 | 1987
  0.055 | 1987
(7 rows)
```

where rt is created from your sample:

```
t=# create table rt(Power_range numrange, unit text, d date);
CREATE TABLE
t=# copy rt from stdin delimiter ';';
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html